# Calling a function within a component class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following variable, `registerForm`, that has been assigned an array of components. This variable has been defined outside of the `Panel` class.

```
const registerForm = [
    <div key={0} style={styles.form.inlineContainer}>
        ...
        <TextField
            floatingLabelText="First Name"
            hintText="First Name"
            floatingLabelFixed={true}
            style={styles.form.inlineContainer.spacing}
            underlineFocusStyle={styles.form.field.borderColor}
            floatingLabelFocusStyle={styles.form.field.color}
            floatingLabelStyle={styles.form.field.fontSize}
            onChange={(input) => this.handleInput(input)}
        />
        ...
    </div>
];
```

I then have a class which has a function `handleInput`. When something is typed into the text field, the following error is produced: `_this.handleInput is not a function`

```
export default class Panel extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            panel: 0
        }
    }

    handlePanelChange = (panel) => {
        this.setState({
            panel: panel
        });
    };

    handleInput = (input) => {
        console.log(input);
    };

    render() {
        const panel = this.state.panel;
        const form = (panel === 0) ? signInForm : registerForm;

        return (
            {form}
        );
    }
}
```

If possible, how can I get the `onChange` event to call `handleInput`?

Comment: create `registerForm` inside the render function, otherwise what is `this`?

Comment: you can use handleInput inside Panel and pass it down to registerFrom or move registerForm inside Panel so this way it recognizes "this".  Also try using arrow function if you do move it inside Panel

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an `array` that will render a UI element, how about creating a component for that? And then you can just pass your method in by `props` as [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props) points out:

```
class Square extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
      <button className="square">
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i} />;
}
```